# Cannot append options into selectpicker dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add `option` into a `selectpicker` button to have a multiple select dropdown button but it doesn't work.

I did include `refresh()` after appending the `option` but it doesn't display in the dropdown list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var unique = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  $('#select1').one('click', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
          $(this).append(`<option value="${unique[i]}">${unique[i]}</option>`);
      }
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" 
        integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="simple_form form-inline">
        <div class="form-group select required">
            <label for="basic-url" class="form-label">Product</label>
            <select class="selectpicker required form-control" multiple id="select1">
                <option value="All">All</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: You're attaching the click event to `#select1`, which is no longer visible in the DOM once the select picker is instantiated, so it cannot be clicked. Hook to a different element and your code works fine

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I use `select1` because the options will be added from the dataset, so when the user clicks the select button, it will add the data into the dropdown list for filtering.

Comment: Target the element which is actually clicked on, such as `$('[data-id="select1"]')` and the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#select1')` is hidden so it cannot receive click events. SelectPicker has its [API docs](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#events), according to which there are a number of non-standard events to listen to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var unique = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  $('#select1').on('show.bs.select', function() {
    console.log('show.bs.select'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
          $(this).append(`<option value="${unique[i]}">${unique[i]}</option>`);
      }
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" 
        integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="simple_form form-inline">
        <div class="form-group select required">
            <label for="basic-url" class="form-label">Product</label>
            <select class="selectpicker required form-control" multiple id="select1">
                <option value="All">All</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of `on` use `one` currently your code is appending options on every click.

Comment: Your code works fine if we use the `one()` to prevent it add more than 1 whenever click.